# Force Google OAuth to request a username/password when authenticating a user

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-openid

When I try to authenticate a user through Google OAuth 1.0, if the user is already logged in with Google, he's automatically asked if he'd like to allow access to my application. I would like to force the user into submitting his/her credentials again to Google, so he may provide a different account than the one he's logged in with (both FB and Twitter OAuth handshake have an option for this).

Also, is there a parameter I can pass on to Google that would make it aware it's in a popup, so it may adjust the layout better ? Again, FB and Twitter take "ownership" of the popup and resize it so their layout fits perfectly. They're also aware of being presented in a popup so a different layout is presented.

Google seems so far behind with its API's. I found the overall implementation difficult to work with, the XML's are creepy and full of useless data, documentation incomplete and overall procedures are not consistent across it's services, or even across the same service!

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `max_auth_age=0` to the first OAuth URL.  This worked for me.

Comment: Nope. Thanks for the suggestion though. I'm using OAuth 1.0 and I believe the `max_auth_age=0` param is for their hybrid or federated auth.

Comment: For reference, this worked for me using Google's OAuth v2.0 (Google+ API)

Comment: thanks! But, how can I implement this using the DotNetOpenAuth framework?

Comment: I try login with that link in my rails "/auth/google_oauth2?max_auth_age=0" but it still not forcing me to re-enter the password when I already logon.